# Ionic 2 Slides Component - How to Access Swiper API

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Using ion-slides component (4 slides) on app welcome page/slides. I need ability for user to skip to last slide. Docs say ion-slides implementation of [Swiper API](http://%3Chttp://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/%3E). I need to access methods like: `mySwiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks);`

Tips on how to implement?

Comment: I'm looking for this, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a function within the options property.

[Original answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getting-swiper-instance/46725).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<ion-slides [options]="options">
               <ion-slide>Slide1</ion-slide>
               <ion-slide>Slide2</ion-slide>
             </ion-slides>',
  directive: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class MyComponent {
  public slider: any;

  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      onlyExternal: false,
      onInit: (slides: any) =>
        this.slider = slides
    }
  }

  click() {
    this.slider.sliderNext(true, 250);
  }
}
```

For further options have a look at the [swiper api](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple solution without custom directives, you can try this

```
  constructor(
    private _app: IonicApp
  ){}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._slider = this._app.getComponent('my-slider');
  }
  goToSlide(slideIndex){
    this.slider.slider.slideTo(slideIndex);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service with your Swiper

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeSwiper {
  swiper = null;

  initSwiper(selector) {
    this.swiper = new Swiper(selector, {
      pagination: '.home-swiper-pagination',
      speed: 400,
      spaceBetween: 100,
      nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev'
    });
  }

  goTo(index) {
    this.swiper.slideTo(index);
  }
}
```

And use it into your @Page

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  providers: [HomeSwiper]
})
export class Home {
  constructor(private swiperService: HomeSwiper) {
    this.swiperService.initSwiper('.home-modal-swiper-container');
  }

  skipSlides() {
    this.swiperService.goTo(indexOfTheLastSlide);
  }
}
```

Comment: With this approach, does that mean I'll need to install Swiper library independent of Ionic 2 Slides implementation?