# How to create a filmstrip/carousel in Ionic2 using swiper library

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to create a carousel like this [image: carousel] and I can do this using this wrapper for swiper library (https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular2-swiper)

But is this possible to achieve my goal by using purely ionic2 and its `ion-slides` components. I would prefer this over adding another, possibly, unnecessary module. Unfortunately, docs aren't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

swiper has been integrated directly into Ionic2... not sure what the question is here?

or you can do it this way [Ionic 2 Slides Component - How to Access Swiper API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739937/ionic-2-slides-component-how-to-access-swiper-api)

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  template:`
<ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-slides  [options]="_options" #mySlider>
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let testSlide of testSlides">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
          </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</ion-content>
`
})
export class HomePage {

  greeting: string;
  testSlides: string[] = [];
  @ViewChild('mySlider') mySlider: any;

  constructor(private nav: NavController) {

    this._options = {
        slidesPerView:3,
        pager: true,
      nextButton: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevButton: ".swiper-button-prev",        
        onInit:()=>{
        }
     }
  setTimeout(()=>{
        for (var i=1; i<6; i++) {
            this.testSlides.push("Slide - "+i);
          }
   },100);

    }
}
```

The Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/ybmDsYICQopis88vDl37?p=preview

The Screenshot -
[image]

Comment: If I use ion-slides I get the full page slider. And can't work out how to control those sliders for example not to be full page.

Comment: Am I suppose to use css to over ride those type of features (E.g slide covering whole screen)  or is there some kind of options am suppose to set.